# Put JavaScript code into a string variable

Tags: javascript, string

I have some data wanted to be represented using [datable with jQuery](https://datatables.net/). As you can see, it is easy to use by including totally two, css and javascript, files. Since, as my project requirement, neither I include any file in project folder or somewhere nor I’m able to connect to the Internet, I need to escape all javascript code into a string variable then use it between `<script></script>` tags. To do so, I make use of [the website](https://www.buildmystring.com/default.php). I think it works pretty well since its result doesn’t yield any compiler error or warning. Whenever I include it as,

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js\"></script>
```

it works. But when I put the content of the `jquery.dataTables.min.js` into a string variable by escaping via the website, I get the following error.

[image]

44th line’s the following part is hightlighted with the cross end symbol on chrome. (I’m not able to put whole code here becuase SO doesn’t permit it.)

```
.warn("jQuery.Deferred exception: "+e.message,e.stack,t)},E.readyException=function(e){g.setTimeout(function(){throw e})};var $=E.Deferred();function F(){v.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",F),g.removeEventListener("load",F),E.ready()}E.fn.ready=function(e){return $.then(e)["catch"](function(e){E.readyException(e)}),this},E.extend({isReady:!1,readyWait:1,ready:function(e){(!0===e?--E.readyWait:E.isReady)||(E.isReady=!0)!==e&&0<--E.readyWait||$.resolveWith(v,[E])}}),E.ready.then=$.then,"complete"===v.readyState||"loading"!==v.readyState&&!v.documentElement.doScroll?g.setTimeout(E.ready):(v.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",F),g.addEventListener("load",F));var z=function(e,t,n,r,i,o,a){var s=0,u=e.length,l=null==n;if("object"===T(n))for(s in i=!0,n)z(e,t,s,n[s],!0,o,a);else if(void 0!==r&&(i=!0,x(r)||(a=!0),l&&(a?(t.call(e,r),t=null):(l=t,t=function(e,t,n){return l.call(E(e),n)})),t))for(;s<u;s++)t(e[s],n,a?r:r.call(e[s],s,t(e[s],n)));return i?e:l?t.call(e):u?t(e[0],n):o},_=/^-ms-/,U=/-([a-z])/g;function V(e,t){return t.toUpperCase()}function X(e){return e.replace(_,"ms-").replace(U,V)}var Q=function(e){return 1===e.nodeType||9===e.nodeType||!+e.nodeType};function Y(){this.expando=E.expando+Y.uid++}Y.uid=1,…………….. STACKOVERFLOW DOESN’T PERMIT LONG TEXT…………………..function(e,t,n){var r,i;if(e&&e.preventDefault&&e.handleObj)return r=e.handleObj,E(e.delegateTarget).off(r.namespace?r.origType+"."+r.namespace:r.origType,r.selector,r.handler),this;if("object"==typeof e){for(i in e)this.off(i,t,e[i]);return this}return!1!==t&&"function"!=typeof t||(n=t,t=void 0),!1===n&&{return g.$===E&&(g.$=xt),e&&g.jQuery===E&&(g.jQuery=bt),E},e||(g.jQuery=g.$=E),E});
```

What’s wrong with my idea? Cannot I apply my idea?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call `.DataTable`? Where is the `<script>` tag in your document? I'm not totally clear on how including the scripts as strings circumvents the lack of internet connection.

Comment: @TylerRoper I call under the script immediately. I’m cognizant of jQuery being called before the script if you mean that one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I put the content of the jquery.dataTables.min.js into a string variable by escaping via the website"? What website? What variable?

Comment: @snr Is your call to `DataTable` wrapped in a `$(function() { ... })` or `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` ? Have you accidentally included jQuery **multiple times?**

Comment: @phuzi There is link if you can carefully glance at the question. As for the variable, assume that a string variable.

Comment: Why are you using buildmystring.com? What settings do you use? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Okay so what I'm getting now after reading the question a few times: You are trying to copy the contents *from* that minified script, run it through an escape tool, and stick it in a `<script> {code here} </script>` instead of linking to it. Is that correct? If so, try getting the *non* minified version working first. At least then you can get useful errors. Once you figure out what errors there are and you account for them, you can move to the minified version instead.

Comment: You're showing a script tag and saying, "this works." Then you're describing something else *without showing it* and saying, "The thing I'm not showing you returns an error." If the problem is that something is giving you an error, showing *that* is better than showing the thing that *isn't* giving you an error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know you typed something in your question, but I am unable to clearly interpret what you mean, I can only assume. Do you mean that you can't store any files besides YOUR files in your project?

Comment: @Matthew yes. I can’t

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks for idea. That’s what I’m trying.